# Java String manipulation whitespace

Tags: java, string, format

I have current string "Model 1467" would like to convert to after "1467_Profile".

Before:
 Medole 1467

After:
   1467_Profile

Comment: `String after = before.split(“\\s”)[1] + “_Profile”;`?

Comment: Is there any *regularity* in your string? Is word `Model` always at same position? Does it always have some number after it? Do you always want to remove `Model XXX` and replace it with `XXX_Profile`?

Comment: "word then numbers" but is word always `Model` or can it be something else?

Comment: Also you said "i always want to **just** take the number then append_Profile", but your example contradicts it because it also removes word `Model` which is little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` with regex like so :

```
String str = "Model 1467";
str = str.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+)$", "$1_Profile");
System.out.println(str);
=> 1467_Profile
```

[**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/FJkU1Z/1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number always comes after the word,

```
String before = "Model 1467";
String after = before.split("\\s")[1]+"_Profile";
System.out.println(after);
```